# Issue with django_db mark in setupclass

Tags: python, django, testing, django-database

Morning, i'm using test inherit from django.test.TestCase and I have problems using setupclass method, because that access to db and and raise this error "Failed: Database access not allowed, use the "django_db" mark to enable", however i'm using the django_db mark. Here is the code:

```
from django.test import TestCase

@pytest.mark.django_db
class ViewAllBeneficiariesTest(TestCase):
''' Tests for Beneficiary '''

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.u = model_mommy_create_user_permission_all()

    def test_clients_view_all_beneficiaries_get_ok(self):
        #Arrange:
        self.client.login(username=self.u.username, password="admin")
        #Act:
        res = self.client.get('/clients/beneficiaries/all/')

        #Assert:
        self.assertEqual(res.status_code, 200)
        self.assertTemplateUsed(res, 'clients/search_beneficiaries.html')

    def test_clients_view_all_beneficiaries_404(self):
        #Arrange:
        self.client.login(username=self.u.username, password="admin")
        #Act:
        res = self.client.get('/clients/beneficiaries/all/')

        #Assert:

        self.assertEqual(res.status_code, 404)

    def test_clients_view_all_beneficiaries_fail(self):
        #Arrange:
        #Act:
        res = self.client.get('/clients/beneficiaries/all/')

        #Assert:

        self.assertEqual(res.status_code, 302)
       self.assertRedirects(res, '/accounts/login/')
```

Comment: Is this the actual indentation of your source?

Comment: No, it's the indentation given to copy. Sorry, i think that i would refactor the code here...

Comment: Done, code refactored ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed in `pytest-django`'s master branch.

You can read about it [here](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-django/issues/117)

I was able to install it with `pip` by issuing the following command -

```
pip install https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-django/zipball/master
```